# create a collection in Mongo Atlas using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> I created a new mongoose model name 'users', and created a new Object
> using it to save a new record to the collection.
>
> after running the code i cant see any collection in Mongo Atlas.
>
> I used .once to check the connection to the Mongo Atlas, but after
> running and getting the profile i needed from the google auth i cant
> see any collection made in Mongo and i cant see any record in the
> Object i created - getting an undefined using a log.

> index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport'); //const passportconfig <=
const app = express();
const { Router } = require('express');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open',()=>{
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app); //authRoutes using app express

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

> users

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const { mongoURI } = require('../config/keys');
//const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const {Schema} = mongoose; //same as line 2 => tell to mongoose object that he have a    property called Schema and use it in new object call Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({ //constructor i
    googleId: String //user will have googleId for now
});

mongoose.model('users', userSchema);//our new collection User and will follow by the userSchema => only creating collection if it dosent exsits only
```

> passport

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
},
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        //console.log('accessToken',accessToken); //allow us to reach to google and show user permissions
        //console.log('refreshToken',refreshToken); //allow us to refresh the accessToken
        console.log('profile',profile);
        new User({googleId:profile.id}).save(); //create a new instance of a User => and get the profile id , .scae => save to the MongoDB
        console.log(User.googleId);
    })
);//passport using new google oauth and handle it
```

after changing to .save(); andd adding arrow func:

```
console.log('profile Id',profile.id);
        new User({ googleId: profile.id}).save(err => {
            console.log(err) 
        });
```

in .save(err =>) i get null output in the terminal.

### working and saving to the collection after adding userNewUrlParser:

```
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
```

---

still getting a - null in the terminal on the save(err=>) func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save is a function you have to call it like

```
        new User({googleId:profile.id}).save(); //create a new instance of a User => and get the profile id , .scae => save to the MongoDB
```

Comment: Thank you it does work. But when i go into the cluster collection i cant find the googleId still get an undefined on the log and no data in the record

Comment: does console.log('profile',profile); working? and showing profile?

Comment: yes, it's working I can see the googleId from the profile of the user but I can't see it in the collection of users in Atlas.

Comment: now, it's working on the atlas and showing data? For showing in the console, pass second parameter to the callback as well. Like, save(err, data => {
            console.log(err) ;
            console.log(data) ;
        });